# Import of H+ ions into the thylakoid space during photosynthesis in plants

Tags: cell-biology, botany, photosynthesis

Why are H+ ions pumped into the thylakoid space as the electrons pass through the cytochrome complex from PS2 to PS1 during photosynthesis?

Comment: This is covered in most texts of biochemistry. Have you tried to find the answer yourself as explained in the [Help Centre](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? Try, for example, [Section 19.3 of Berg et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22538/) online.